# Cyclic subgroup proof question

Tags: group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group and let $k$ be a positive integer.  Then $\langle a^k \rangle = \langle a^{\gcd(n,k)} \rangle \text{ and } |a^k| = n / \gcd(n,k).$

The proof starts by letting $d = \gcd(n,k) \text{ and let } k = dr.$  Then since $a^k = (a^d)^r$, ***we have by closure that $\langle a^k \rangle \subseteq \langle a^d \rangle$.***

I understand that $\langle a^k \rangle = \{(a^k)^n : n \in \Bbb Z \}$ and $\langle a^d \rangle = \{(a^d)^n : n \in \Bbb Z \}$, but how does closure imply this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^k=(a^d)^r$, $a^k\in\langle a^d\rangle$, but $\langle a^k\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $a^k$. Hence the result.

Comment: Excuse me for asking you to spell this out but: (1) why is it that $\langle a^k \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $a^k$? (2) What do you mean when you say "subgroup?" Which group that $\langle a^k \rangle$ is a subgroup of, if any, is relevant here? (3) Why does (1) imply that $\langle a^k \rangle \subseteq \langle a^d \rangle$.

Comment: @Mailbox (1): If $G$ is a group and $S$ is a subset of $G$, then $\langle S\rangle$ is by definition the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. It is the set of all products of elements of $S$.
(2): I don't get your question, if $g$ is an element of a group $G$, then $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$. 
(3): Since $a^k$ is an element of $\langle a^d\rangle$ and $\langle a^d\rangle$ is a group, all powers of $a^k$ are elements of $\langle a^d\rangle$, but the set of all powers of $a^k$ is precisely $\langle a^k\rangle$, whence $\langle a^k\rangle\subset\langle a^d\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $(a^k)^n = (a^{dr})^n = (a^d)^{rn}$ to see that every power of $a^k$ is also a power of $a^d$, hence $\langle a^k\rangle \subset \langle a^d\rangle$.

Comment: Why is that a proper subset, and not a full subset ($\subseteq$)?

Comment: Like many mathematicians, I use this symbol -- $\subset$ -- to mean "is a subset of." And because every set is a subset of itself, that symbol includes the possibility that the items on the left and right are actually equal. There are certainly places where using it to mean "proper subset" might be helpful, and using the distinguishing "full subset" notation might clarify things. But it's not what I generally do (indeed, I don't even know the LaTeX name for the full-subset symbol!), so...I guess you get what you pay for.